Parsing Version type with Json.NET during deserialization throws an error
I have a model that I serialised using Json.NET, however, when I de-serialise, I get an error when it attempts to parse a Version type property.
The serialised JSON is below:
{
  "Releases": [
    {
      "Id": "01GPM6T600TCF9NJXXG6WHPSZP",
      "Description": "Description",
      "InformativeVersion": "v320",
      "InformativeReleaseDate": "2024-05-17T00:00:00",
      "Version": {
        "Major": 320,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Build": 0,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
      },
      "BinaryUrl": "",
      "BinarySha256": ""
    },
    {
      "Id": "01GMKTW700BGT0YHN99T1GXS6P",
      "Description": "Description",
      "InformativeVersion": "v309",
      "InformativeReleaseDate": "2024-04-03T00:00:00",
      "Version": {
        "Major": 309,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Build": 0,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
      },
      "BinaryUrl": "",
      "BinarySha256": ""
    }
  ]
}

The error I get is below:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected token or value when parsing version. Token: StartObject, Value:. Path 'Releases[0].Version', line 8, position 18.'

The C# object looks like this:
public class ReleaseManifest
{
    public Release[] Releases { get; set; }
}

public class Release
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string InformativeVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime InformativeReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public Version Version { get; set; }
    public string BinaryUrl { get; set; }
    public string BinarySha256 { get; set; }
}

Any idea on how to go about resolving this error is appreciated.

This is different from the suggested linked question as I have tried the answer there and it doesn't work either.
I would prefer not writing a custom serialiser for this.


What does the (C#) object you're deserializing into look like?

Thanks for the question, I have updated the question to include the object.

Now also add the Model for Version :) Newtonsoft seems to be surprised by the json indicating an object for the version.

My initial thought is that newtonsoft may have a custom deserializer but not a custom serializer, and may be expecting a string representation instead of object representation, such as "309.0.0"

@Fildor, I am using the .NET Version class.

=> this one ? - Just to be absolutely clear?

@Matthew I used the Json.NET VersionConverter for serialising and de-serialising, but still got that error.

@Fildor, yes, that one.

The first line of the documentation for VersionConverter says that it converts from a string (e.g. "1.2.3.4").

Does this answer your question? Why System.Version in JSON string does not deserialize correctly?

@fildor the -1 might be used internally to represent "lack of value" so the behavior you are seeing could be expected.

@Fildor - when Revision is -1, you need to use the constructor that doesn't take a Revision argument.  And when Build is null, you need to use the constructor that doesn't take either.  The VersionConverter from your linked question doesn't seem to do that properly.

Hah, was too eager to replicate the exact values ...

@Fildor - I wrote my answer before seeing your comment.  It looks like the question is a duplicate, but the answers seem obsolete (Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JsonConverter is built-in and used automatically, and the custom VersionConverter has bugs).  Should we mark this as a duplicate and move my answer over there?

@dbc Sounds like a plan to me.

You can't mark this as a dupe because as the answer in the linked question doesn't work for me. In addition, I would prefer not to go with a custom serialiser as this is not a personal project.

@codejockie - In addition, I would prefer not to go with a custom serialiser as this is not a personal project. -- what do you mean by this?  Do you mean you don't want to use a custom JsonConverter?  Your question does not state that.

@codejockie - You can't mark this as a dupe because as the answer in the linked question doesn't work for me. - right, those answers are broken.  The idea would be to add my answer there so that question has at least one non-broken answer.

@dbc "at" me when you do.

@Fildor - I added an answer to Why System.Version in JSON string does not deserialize correctly? here: link.

@Fildor - Ugh, found something nasty.  Turns out that Json.NET has different default serializations for Version in .NET Core and .NET Framework.  No idea why.  I rewrote my answer to the possible duplicate to mention this.

I just had a crazy idea: Why not make that .Net-typed Version property Json-Ignored and prallel it with a custom-made "MyVersion" class that just behaves as you would expect with all default json serialization settings?

@Fildor - that can work, but if the OP needs to support both the string and object JSON formats they will need to either add a custom converter for MyVersion or use JToken instead and parse it in the setter.

Your problem is that Json.NET is expecting your Version to be serialized as a string, i.e. "320.0.0", when in fact it is serialized as a JSON object.  Json.NET will assume that Version will be serialized as a string:

In .NET Core, always. See this answer to Why System.Version in JSON string does not deserialize correctly? for details.
Whenever the built-in converter VersionConverter has been added to JsonSerializerSettings.Converters.

If you need to deserialize a Version that was serialized as a JSON object but also want to support the string format, you will need to create your own custom JsonConverter<Version> for that.  The following, which has been added as this answer to Why System.Version in JSON string does not deserialize correctly?, is one possible converter.  Its ReadJson() method checks to see whether the incoming token is a JSON string or an object, and deserializes appropriately:
public class VersionObjectConverter : JsonConverter<Version>
{
    public VersionObjectConverter() : this(false) { } // Serialize as a string by default
    public VersionObjectConverter(bool serializeAsObject) { this.SerializeAsObject = serializeAsObject; }

    static readonly Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.VersionConverter InnerConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.VersionConverter();
    bool SerializeAsObject { get; set; }

    class VersionDto
    {
        public int Major; public int Minor; public int Build = -1; public int Revision = -1; public Int16 MajorRevision = -1; public Int16 MinorRevision = -1;
        public Version ToVersion()
        {
            if (Build == -1)
                return new Version(Major, Minor);
            else if (Revision == -1)
                return new Version(Major, Minor, Build);
            else
                return new Version(Major, Minor, Build, Revision);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Version value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else if (SerializeAsObject)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new VersionDto { Major = value.Major, Minor = value.Minor, Build = value.Build, Revision = value.Revision, MajorRevision = value.MajorRevision, MinorRevision = value.MinorRevision});
        else
            InnerConverter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null: return null;
            case JsonToken.String: return (Version)InnerConverter.ReadJson(reader, objectType, hasExistingValue ? existingValue : null, serializer);
            case JsonToken.StartObject: return serializer.Deserialize<VersionDto>(reader).ToVersion();
            default: throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unknown token type {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

Then add it to options and deserialize e.g. as follows:
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new VersionObjectConverter(serializeAsObject : true) },
};

var manifest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReleaseManifest>(json, settings);

Or if you want Version to be re-serialized as a string, pass new serializeAsObject : false to the VersionObjectConverter constructor:
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new VersionObjectConverter(serializeAsObject : false) },
};

Alternatively, if you would prefer not to modify the global JsonSerializerSettings of your project, you may apply the converter directly to your model using JsonConverterAttribute:
public class Release
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string InformativeVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime InformativeReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(VersionObjectConverter), new object [] { false })]
    public Version Version { get; set; }
    public string BinaryUrl { get; set; }
    public string BinarySha256 { get; set; }
}

Do note that System.Text.Json has an attribute of the same name so it is safer to use the fully qualified name.
Demo fiddle here.

I used the VersionConverter to serialise and de-serialise but the serialised string result contains an object instead of a string which was I was expecting.

@codejockie - pass serializeAsObject : false to the constructor.

where do I pass that?

@codejockie - if you don't want to add your converter to your settings, you can apply it directly to your model using [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(VersionObjectConverter), new object [] { false })].  But one way or another you will need to use a custom JsonConverter because Json.NET serializes Version as a string by default, and because Version is an immutable type with multiple parameterized constructors so Json.NET will not know how to construct it as an object.
